Abel Integral Equation with f(x) Constant
I found in a source that for the variant of Abel's Integral Equation with Fixed Limits and a constant $\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)$, namely
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\operatorname{g}\left(t\right)\left\vert x - t\right\vert^{-\gamma}\,{\rm d}t = \operatorname{f}\left(x\right) = \lambda
$$
for a fixed $\ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\ $ and any $\ 0 \le x,\ \gamma \le 1, \ $ the solution is given by $$
\operatorname{g}\left(t\right) \propto \left[t\left(1 - t\right)\right]^{-\left(1\ -\ \gamma\right)/2}
$$
I was wondering, how does one go about proving this ?.

The solution is in Whittiker and Watson “A course on Modern Analysis” in the chapter on integral equations (i love this book! and abels equation is fascinating), pg 238 https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/PHYS181/Βιβλια/E.%20T.%20Whittaker%2C%20G.%20N.%20Watson%20-%20A%20Course%20of%20Modern%20Analysis%20%282021%2C%20Cambridge%20University%20Press%29.pdf. t

@MattCalhoun so I was able to find this formula elsewhere - I think it only applies to the equation when the upper bound of the integral is $x$ rather than a fixed constant $b$.  Indeed, if you actually try the closed-form solution presented in that text, it doesn't seem to match the correct solution.
